# Move focus and selection from tk entry to ttk treeview with binding key

Tags: python, treeview, ttk

I want to change focus and selection from tk entry to ttk treeview section with binding key.

[image]

Above figure, present cursor and focus in entry section and want to move focus and selection to ttk treeview section

```
    def treeview_focus(self, event):

    child_id = self.tree.get_children()[-1]
    
    self.tree.focus(child_id)
    self.tree.selection_set(child_id)
    self.tree.selection_add(child_id)
```

with focus, selection method, I can highlight specific list of item in treeview but I can't move item list by up and down key on keyboard because cursor still in entry.

If I click directly list of items in treeview with mouse, I can move up and down of lists with my keyboard.

My question is how can I focus treeview section and can use my keyboard for selecting items in treeview section without mouse clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is problem.

should use focus_set() method first for selecting and focusing whole treeview

```
self.tree.focus_set()
self.tree.focus(child_id)
```

above sequence, I can select last items of treeview and can move lists with my keyboard